# Shutdown now on ExecutionException

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I read a lot of post about `ExecutorService`, but I can't find the way of doing what I need.

I need some concurrent threads. When any of them throw a custom exception all the remaining tasks are canceled.

This is an example of what I did. The task are working concurrent, but aren't interrupted on exception.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();

        futures.add(executorService.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println("Task 1 done");
                return null;
            }
        }));

        futures.add(executorService.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Task 2 done");
                if (true) {
                    throw new CustomException("Error on task 2");
                }
                return null;
            }
        }));
        executorService.shutdown();

        try {
            executeFutures(futures);
        } catch (CustomException ex) {
            System.out.println("Received:" + ex.getMessage());
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }    
    }

    private static void executeFutures(List<Future> futures) throws CustomException {
        try {
            for (Future f : futures) {
                f.get();
            }
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof CustomException) {
                throw (CustomException) e.getCause();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

This is the output:

```
Task 2 done  //exception is thrown here but task1 continue.
Task 1 done
Received:Error on task 2
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't check anywhere in the code for task 1 to see if the current thread was interrupted.

Comment: I agree, but where will be that information about each thread failure? , and  if are more than two threads the thrown can happen after the question is made. Maybe my approach is wrong, but I don't see a good one.

Comment: From the docs: There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate. - you need to actually handle the case where your task gets interrupted. Task 1 was already running when task 2 interrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that the method `executeFutures` make the main thread call `f.get()` on the first `Future` instance corresponding to the long task, which makes it wait the duration of the task so at least 5 seconds whatever happens. Once done it will then call `f.get()` on the second `Future` which is already over so it gets immediately the `CustomException` from the `ExecutionException` and calls `executorService.shutdownNow()` but it is already too late as there is no more tasks left to interrupt.

What you could do, is to use a decorator of type `Callable` that will automatically shutdown the thread pool when a `CustomException` is thrown, this way the thread pool will be shutdown directly by the thread that has executed the task that throws the exception instead of using the main thread.

Something like this:

```
public class AutoShutdown<V> implements Callable<V> {

    private final ExecutorService executorService;
    private final Callable<V> task;

    public AutoShutdown(final ExecutorService executorService, final Callable<V> task) {
        this.executorService = executorService;
        this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public V call() throws Exception {
        try {
            return task.call();
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            executorService.shutdownNow();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will need to submit your tasks through the decorator as next:

```
futures.add(
    executorService.submit(
        new AutoShutdown<>(
            executorService,
            new Callable<Void>() {
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println("Task 1 done");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        )
    )
);

futures.add(
    executorService.submit(
        new AutoShutdown<>(
            executorService,
            new Callable<Void>() {
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    System.out.println("Task 2 done");
                    if (true) {
                        throw new CustomException("Error on task 2");
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }
        )
    )
);
```

**Output:**

```
Task 2 done
```

As you can see in the output, the task one has been interrupted soon enough.

---

> The message "`Received:Error on task 2`" was not thrown, so it looks
>   like a successful execution, and is not the case

No it is only because the first call to `f.get()` throws an `InterruptedException` as expected which makes it exit from `executeFutures` because the catch is performed outside the loop, move it inside the loop as next:

```
private static void executeFutures(List<Future> futures) throws CustomException {
    for (Future f : futures) {
        try {
            f.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof CustomException) {
                throw (CustomException) e.getCause();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Task 2 done
Received:Error on task 2
```

Comment: You are in the good way, so I plus the answer, but the message "Received:Error on task 2" was not thrown, so it looks like a successful execution, and is not the case.

Comment: No it is only because the first call to `f.get()` throws an `InterruptedException`as expected which makes it exit from `executeFutures` because the `catch` is performed outside the loop and the current code do nothing on `InterruptedException`, move it inside the loop then you will get what you expect